# Is Pandora Unofficial REST API broken

Tags: api, authentication, pandora

up until fairly recently I had been able to use the Pandora Unofficial REST API to login and get my pandora stations, etc.

It now appears the pandora login authentication has changed and no longer works as described on the pandora unofficial REST api wiki:  https://6xq.net/pandora-apidoc/rest/authentication/#user-login

previously sending this request:

```
{
    "existingAuthToken": null,
    "keepLoggedIn": true,
    "password": "secretpassword",
    "username": "email@example.com"
}
```

resulted in a working authentication token.  this no longer seems to work.  It also appears when login into the Panadora.com website it is now logging in with a request that looks like this:

```
{
"existingAuthToken": null,
"username": "email@example.com",
"password": "secretpassword",
"keepLoggedIn": true,
"OZ_TC":"AFpt...",
"OZ_DT":"1ZsvOA5s...",

"OZ_SG":"K4@<b#IoWptdRcS:..."
}
```

where the "OZ_TC", "OZ_DT", and "OZ_SG" appear to be some required keys or time related signature.

Does anyone know if the unofficial REST api is broken?

Comment: Looks like Pandora started using WhiteOps for bot detection. You should see a JS file from Pandora that contains the code for generating the fields you mentioned. I found a similar version here: https://smitop.com/whiteops-main.js. Is the unofficial rest api broken? It appears so. Pandora updated their process so the docs are stale.

Comment: have you had any luck working through this issue? I'm also interested in getting the REST API functional again.

Comment: @h0r53 it does appear you are correct. It appears, Pandora is now hitting this address, https://s.hoplon.pandora.com/sri/config.json?dt=....   then passing this to this script<script src="https://s.hoplon.pandora.com/static/pandora/4.80.9/pagespeed.js?dt=5222681607985354683000&amp;psv=4.80.9&amp;ci=522268&amp;spa=1&amp;pd=acc&amp;mo=2&amp;di=pandora.com&amp;si=SXMP&amp;ui=1195743247" async=""></script> to get the correct values to pass to the login .  this does look like it is something from whiteOps, obfiscated.

Comment: this page also looks like they are trying to deal with the same issue:  https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/PromyLOPh/pandora-apidoc/45/803479016

Comment: visit the actual github page for pandora-apidoc by PromyLOPh. There is continued discussion there that I've contributed to.